# SQL query column doesn't exist

Tags: python, sql, pandasql

I have seen many answers about similar SQL queries, but for some reason none of the solutions works with my query. 
I am trying to read my query into a pandas data frame matching them to my (list) variables from before. 
Thank you for any suggestion

```
genename = names
location = residuelist

query ='SELECT "KINASE_NAME", "GENE_NAME", "RESIDUE" FROM public."Phosphosite_table" WHERE "GENE_NAME" LIKE "%s" AND "RESIDUE" LIKE "%s"' %(genename, location) 
df = pd.read_sql(query, con= pg.connect(conn_string))
```

I get a column doesn't exist error, and I don't understand how to solve it anymore. Thank you for any help

After the suggestions in the comments I tried to change the query to this:

```
query ='SELECT KINASE_NAME, GENE_NAME, RESIDUE FROM public.Phosphosite_table WHERE GENE_NAME LIKE '%s' AND RESIDUE LIKE '%s'' %(genename, location) 
    df = pd.read_sql(query, con= pg.connect(conn_string))
```

This way I get a syntax error just after LIKE
The genename and location variables are lists and basically I'm trying to access PostgreSQL db through python (using psycopg), but as I couldn't resolve the error, now I'm trying to use pandas.read_sql function.

I have very little experience in SQL, so I really thank for all suggestions and corrections

Comment: you don’t need quotes around your column names unless they are a reserved keyword

Comment: And in Standard SQL strings are single quoted, doble quotes indicate object names: `LIKE '%s'`. What's your DBMS? And what's the actual error message?

Comment: Also are your columns really named in CAPS? This is unusual in SQL. And this is vulnerable to SQL injection. And `like` requires `%` on either side of the search parameters, assuming this is SQLite

Comment: `location = residuelist` also looks like this parameter is a list, not a string. There are currently way too many unknowns to be able to pin this down for you, sorry.

Comment: @roganjosh: LIKE does not *require* `%` on both sides, of course you can use it if this is what you want.

Comment: @dnoeth my goodness. Good correction, I've conflated LIKE with the wildcard match. Sorry.

Comment: Column names are capital, yes. So I tried to change it as :
    query ='SELECT KINASE_NAME, GENE_NAME, RESIDUE FROM public."Phosphosite_table" WHERE GENE_NAME LIKE '%s' AND RESIDUE LIKE '%s'' %(genename, location)

And I get a syntax error at  '%s'

Comment: One of my other comments was that `location = residuelist` suggests that `location` is a list, not a string. That would cause a syntax error when the string is interpolated

Comment: you have mismatching quotes now —> ‘%s” has two types of quotations in it, and also remove the quotes from the table name itself you don’t need that either